# Помогите добавить классы к определенному тегу Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
pin.each(function(){
        var mapCityID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        if(mapCityID == cityID)       
          jQuery(this).addClass('pin-pulsing');
        else
          jQuery(this).removeClass('pin-pulsing');          
      });
```

```html
<div class="map">
        <div class="pin pin-pulsing" id="moscow">
          <div class="dot">
            <span class="hide">Moscow</span></div>
          <div class="pulse sprite sprite-pin-pulse">
            <span class="hide">icon</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin" id="almaty">
          <div class="dot">
            <span class="hide">Alamaty</span></div>
          <div class="pulse sprite sprite-pin ">
            <span class="hide">icon</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin" id="tashkent">
          <div class="dot">
            <span class="hide">Tashkent</span></div>
          <div class="pulse sprite sprite-pin">
            <span class="hide">icon</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin" id="bishkek">
          <div class="dot">
            <span class="hide">Bishkek</span></div>
          <div class="pulse sprite sprite-pin">
            <span class="hide">icon</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin" id="seoul">
          <div class="dot">
            <span class="hide">Seoul</span></div>
          <div class="pulse sprite sprite-pin">
            <span class="hide">icon</span></div>
        </div>
    <div class="pin" id="dushanbe">
          <div class="dot">
            <span class="hide">Dushanbe</span></div>
          <div class="pulse sprite sprite-pin">
            <span class="hide">icon</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Есть html и код на Jquery, который в зависимости выбранного элемента, добавляет элементу с эти id класс или удаляет его.
Вопрос такой: Что добавить в Jquery, чтобы класс добавлялся не только элементу this, но и например ,вложенному в этот this, диву.
Например, в примере HTMl элементом this является див с классом 'pin',к нему и добавляется классс. а как мне добавить класс к дивам внутри pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `children()`

```
pin.each(function(){
    var mapCityID = $(this).attr('id');
    if(mapCityID == cityID)       
    $(this).addClass('pin-pulsing').children().addClass('pin-pulsing');
    else
    $(this).removeClass('pin-pulsing').children().removeClass('pin-pulsing');        
});
```